# Debugging ssh shared keys

Tags: ssh

I am unable to connect at distance from my server to another one, and can't understand why...

```
romain@wk:~/.ssh$ ssh -vvv romain@192.168.0.39
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.39 [192.168.0.39] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/romain/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
```

Which is strange to me because I have

```
romain@wk: cd /home/romain/.ssh/
romain@wk:~/.ssh$ ls -la
total 28
drwx------ 2 romain romain 4096 Feb 12 18:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 romain romain 4096 Feb 12 18:51 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 romain romain  400 Feb 11 18:46 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 romain romain  137 Feb 11 18:46 environment
-rw------- 1 romain romain 1766 Feb 11 18:46 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 romain romain  400 Feb 11 18:44 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 romain romain  222 Feb 11 18:44 known_hosts
```

is the ["Could not load "/home/romain/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key"] referencing a file on the local server or on the distant server ?

EDIT

server log :

```
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug1: trying public key file /home/romain/.ssh/authorized_keys
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/romain
```

directory details :

```
romain@pl:/home$ cd /home/
romain@pl:/home$ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 21 romain romain 4096 Feb 12 19:42 romain
drwxr-xr-x  7 root   root   4096 Feb 10 18:32 users
```

romain's id :

```
romain@pl:/home$ id -u romain
1000
```

Log context :

```
romain@pl:/var/log$ cat /var/log/auth.log | grep refused -C 10
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED [preauth]
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 23 [preauth]
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 22
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x55f3e1d864b0
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug1: trying public key file /home/romain/.ssh/authorized_keys
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/romain
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug1: trying public key file /home/romain/.ssh/authorized_keys2
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/romain/.ssh/authorized_keys2': No such file or directory
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: Failed publickey for romain from 192.168.0.38 port 46259 ssh2: RSA 70:79:60:2c:96:12:05:17:b2:2e:a3:64:fe:38:45:8b
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x55f3e1d864b0 is not allowed
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-rsa [preauth]
Feb 12 19:45:17 pl sshd[28579]: debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password" [preauth]
```

Comment: the message "Could not load "/home/romain/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key" is just noise. If you look further to the log, you see that the key is successfully loaded and used. What is your actual error you got from client and on server?

Comment: The log here is at the client level. How could I get the error log from server ?

Comment: The errors are loged on the server using syslog. Where are the actual files, depends on distribution. If the logs do not contain enough of data, you can try to set `LogLevel DEBUG3` in `sshd_config`, restart server and then try to connect. There will be a lot of messages, but they will tel you why was the key rejected.

Comment: I am on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: logs are on : cat /var/log/auth.log [ I edited the question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message

```
bad ownership or modes for directory /home/romain
```

tells you that these permissions

```
drwxrwxrwx 21 romain romain 4096 Feb 12 19:42 romain
```

are wrong. You probably played around with permissions on your home directory some time back. There are two possible solutions:

1. Fix permissions: `chmod go-w /home/romain` (the directory chain to the `authorized_keys` file can not be writable by any other user)
2. Use `StrictModes No` in your `sshd_config` and restart server.

Both of the option should help you, but I recommend the first one.

Comment: Actually the directory's mode is [drwxrwxrwx 21 romain romain 4096 Feb 12 19:42 romain ]

Comment: Yes. I edited the answer with more details. It is much worse :)